# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/rixo/public_html/login/process.php on line 41

Tags: php, syntax

I am new to php. I keep having this error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/rixo/public_html/login/process.php on line 41

Here is the full code - http://pastebin.com/8Yqmk0MX

If you could look through it for me and see what is the problem it would be a great help.

-Thank you in advance

Comment: Although, we helped you fix the problem, this sort of question is not welcomed in our community. Please keep that is mind next time ;). Why dont you read the [faq]s?

Answer (score 3):

Its due to unclosed quote on this line

```
$checkuser = mysql_query('SELECT username FROM user WHERE username='$user');
```

Fix it

```
$checkuser = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username='$user'");
```

---

**Update:**

Found another query error on line 61 of the paste. There is mismatching quotes

```
$write = “INSERT INTO user (username, password, email) VALUES ('$user', '$pwd', '$mail’)';
```

Fix them

```
$write = "INSERT INTO user (username, password, email) VALUES ('$user', '$pwd', '$mail')";
```

Comment: Thank you man, but now it says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/rixo/public_html/login/process.php on line 59" :/

Comment: @Jack-T look at the other answer too ;)

Comment: I have man :) but the error is still coming up :/

Comment: Also the same case with this query: `$write = “INSERT INTO user (username, password, email) VALUES ('$user', '$pwd', '$mail’)';` Last quote needs to be a double :)

Comment: @Jack-T, Found another error, check the update

Comment: Thank you @starx ! It worked :D and Paul and Cassie Carter and satya! Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
if (isset($_POST["save"]) && $_POST["user"] && $_POST["pwd"] && $_POST["mail"])
```

to

```
if ((isset($_POST["save"]) && $_POST["user"] && $_POST["pwd"] && $_POST["mail"]))
```

Comment: Thank you man! I've changed that now but I get this error now "
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/rixo/public_html/login/process.php on line 59"

Comment: change this elseif (isset($_POST["save"]) && $_POST["user"] && $_POST["pwd"] && $_POST["mail"]) to elseif ((isset($_POST["save"]) && $_POST["user"] && $_POST["pwd"] && $_POST["mail"]))

Comment: to have all conditions under one parenthesis as each of them are separate